# how to launch a sequential code on gpu

Tags: openacc

I have a CPU code:

```
 `if(number_of_pushed_particles<N&&number_of_alive_particles<K)
 {
   push_particle();
   number_of_pushed_particles++;
 }`
```

Here number_of_pushed_particles, number_of_alive_particles, K and N are int, K and N are const. The function push_particle() is:

```
 `push_particle()
 {
   particles[LIFE].id=++MAX_ELEMENT;
   particles[LIFE].rx=0.0;
   particles[LIFE].ry=0.0;
   particles[LIFE].rz=0.0;
   ...
   ++LIFE;
 }
```

`Particle is a structure of floats.The array Particle particles[0:GL], integer variables LIFE and MAX_ELEMENT are statically allocated on the device. That is why i do not want to use #pragma acc update host/device before/after calling the push_particle() function and lose time for copying data. How can i launch this sequential code on the GPU?

Answer (score 1):

The OpenACC 2.6 standard which was just ratified includes a "serial" region but it will be a bit before this support is added to the various compiler implementations.

The current method is to use a "parallel" region and set "num_gangs(1)" and "vector_length(1)".

Something like:

```
push_particle()
 {
#pragma acc parallel num_gangs(1) vector_length(1) present(particles)
{
   particles[LIFE].id=++MAX_ELEMENT;
   particles[LIFE].rx=0.0;
   particles[LIFE].ry=0.0;
   particles[LIFE].rz=0.0;
   ...
   ++LIFE;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why do you omit the "num_workers(1)" clause?

Comment: How to be with a variable allocated on the device? When i try to write in main() LIFE=0;

Comment: (LIFE is allocated on the device). The compiler says: ACEELERATOR RESTRICTION: unsupported statement type: opcode=ACCPLOOP.

Comment: Whent i try to follow your advice and write:

Comment: #pragma acc parallel num_gangs(1) vector_length(1) present(particles)
{
  LIFE=0;

Comment: } The compiler says: PGCC_S-0155-Illegal context for pragma: acc parallel.

Comment: I omitted "num_workers" since it defaults to 1.  You can add it, but it's not needed.  I'd need to see a reproducing example to see what's wrong with "LIFE".  For the illegal context, I'd also need to see how you're using the directive.  I'd assume it's because you have it inside another compute region, but it looks to be by itself in the code you posted on the PGI User Forum.